# error while loading fmu with pyfmi's method load_fmu

Tags: python, load, version, fmi, pyfmi

I try to load an FMU with PyFMI's *load_fmu* method. It throws the following Error:

```
File "src\pyfmi\fmi.pyx", line 8109, in pyfmi.fmi.load_fmu
pyfmi.fmi.FMUException: The FMU version could not be determined. Removing C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\JModelica.org\jm_tmp1rxrafe4

FMIL: module = b'FMILIB', log level = 5: b'Allocating FMIL context'
FMIL: module = b'FMILIB', log level = 5: b'Detecting FMI standard version'
FMIL: module = b'FMIZIP', log level = 5: b'Unpacking FMU into C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\JModelica.org\\jm_tmp1rxrafe4'

FMIL: module = b'FMIZIP', log level = 1: b'Unpacking of FMU C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\fmus\\model.fmu into C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\JModelica.org\\jm_tmp1rxrafe4 failed'

FMIL: module = b'JMPRT', log level = 5: b'Removing C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\JModelica.org\\jm_tmp1rxrafe4'
```

The FMU Version is 2.0 and is contained in the .xml description.
I am using Windows 10 64-bit and the FMU contains a win64 binary.

Comment: Have you checked the FMU with the https://github.com/modelica-tools/FMUComplianceChecker or even better (because it contains even more checks) tried to run/check  it with fmpy https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy  ?
Can you simulate the FMU in any other FMI importing tool?
What is the exporting tool? Is it on the FMI tools list and does it participate in the FMI Cross Check? https://fmi-standard.org/tools/

Comment: Yes, I simulated it with FMPy and it worked just fine. I eventually executed the script on a linux machine with the same FMU and got rid of the error.